# Why won't my python (3.9.13) logging handler write debug to a file?

Tags: python, logging

I'm trying to configure logging so that INFO and lower will write to screen and DEBUG will write to a file.  I have two handlers, a console and a file.  The console is setLevel to WARNING and the file is setLevel to DEBUG.

No matter what combination of levels I try, the script will not write to file for anything less than WARNING.  If I put both to DEBUG, it will create the file, but it will be empty.

Python 3.9.13, Windows 10, VSC 1.70.2

```
import logging

# 1-Create logger
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__) # name of the current module.
# Create handlers - console -> std.out
c_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
f_handler = logging.FileHandler('file.log')
# 2-Set the level of the handlers.
c_handler.setLevel(logging.WARNING) # > INFO -> CONSOLE
f_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG) # > DEBUG -> FILE
# 3-Create a formatter for each handler.
c_format = logging.Formatter('%(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
f_format = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
# 4-Associate handlers and formatters
c_handler.setFormatter(c_format)
f_handler.setFormatter(f_format)
# 5-link handlers to custom logger object.
logger.addHandler(c_handler)
logger.addHandler(f_handler)
# Logging config completed.
logger.debug('This is debug')
logger.warning('This is a warning message.')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your handlers' levels are set correctly. The problem is that the logger's level defaults to `logging.WARNING` (30). Lower the logger's level and you'll see debug messages in the file.

```
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

Comment: Thanks @iforapsy - I just came back here to say that.  You're absolutely right - thanks for the fast reply.